# Getting Error While Creating Project Hotel Management System

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I am trying to create a project which is Hotel Management System. I am stuck in a mid way as I am new to it so I need a help from you guys. I am creating a GUI project on netbeans and MySql.

```
private void jTable2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    d = (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
    int selectIndex = jTable2.getSelectedRow();
    
    jLabel12.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,0).toString());
    txtname.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,1).toString());
    txtphone.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,2).toString());
    **txtcheckin.setDate(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,3));
    txtcheckout.setDate(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,3));**
    txtrnumber.setSelectedItem(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,5).toString());
    txtrtype.setSelectedItem(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,6).toString());
    txtbtype.setSelectedItem(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,7).toString());
    txtamount.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,8).toString());
    
    jButton1.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Above there are two lines (enclose in double asterisks) in which txtcheckin belongs to check in date and txtcheckout belongs to check out date. Basically I want that when I click on table the relevant data showed me on the relevant text field. Checkin and Checkout is a jDateChooser and there type is String.
I also tried doing txtcheckin.setText and txtcheckout.setText but still showing error The Error is shown Below.

[image: Error I am Getting]

Comment: Why does `txtcheckin` and `txtcheckout` retrieve a date from the same table column of the selected table row? Is this a typo?

Comment: The error message is quite direct: Whatever You return from `getValueOf` is of a type not compatible with the type expected by `setDate`. Square peg, round hole.

Comment: By the way, both `Date` classes are terrible supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Search Stack Overflow to learn more, as this has been covered many many many times already.

Answer (score 1):

Anyways...to get what you currently have to work your mouseClicked event code might look something like this (read the comments in code):

```
private void jTable2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {     
    // txtcheckin  is a JDateChooser.
    // txtcheckout is a JDateChooser.
      
    javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel d = (javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
        
    // Get the selected JTable row index value.
    int selectIndex = jTable2.getSelectedRow();
    if (selectIndex == -1) { return; } // No JTable row selected so get outta here.
        
    jLabel12.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,0).toString());
    txtname.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,1).toString());
    txtphone.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,2).toString());
        
    /* Get the dates contained in column 4 (index 3) and column 5 (index 4)
       of the selected JTable row. To retrieve the data from these table 
       columns as string you need to use the 'toString()' method since the 
       getValueAt() method returns an Object even if the table model has 
       these columns set to String.                                  */
    String dateIN = d.getValueAt(selectIndex, 3).toString();
    String dateOUT = d.getValueAt(selectIndex, 4).toString();
        
    // Apply the date String from JTable cells to JDateChoosers Text Fields.
    java.util.Date dateToSetIN;
    java.util.Date dateToSetOUT;
                
    // A Try/Catch must be used here due to parsing.
    try {
        /* The date format supplied to the SimpleDateFormat constructor
           must be the same format that is used within the JTable cell.
           However, the date format set in the JDateChooser's dateFormatString 
           property can be whatever format you like to be displayed within 
           its own Text Field. A similar format would be preferable.    */
        // Make sure there is actually a date string (the cell could be empty)
        if (!dateIN.isEmpty()) {
            dateToSetIN = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").parse(dateIN);
            /* Ensure similar format in JDateChooser Text Field. This is
               optional and can be removed!           */
            txtcheckin.setDateFormatString("MMM dd, yyyy");
            // Set the selected JTable Date into JDateChooser...
            txtcheckin.setDate(dateToSetIN);
        }
        else {
            /* Clear the JDateChooser Text Field since there is
               no date in the selected row anyways.           */
            txtcheckin.setDate(null);
        }
            
        // Make sure there is actually a date string (the cell could be empty)
        if (!dateOUT.isEmpty()) {
            dateToSetOUT = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").parse(dateOUT);
            /* Ensure similar format in JDateChooser Text Field. This is
               optional and can be removed!           */
            txtcheckout.setDateFormatString("MMM dd, yyyy");
            // Set the selected JTable Date into JDateChooser...
            txtcheckout.setDate(dateToSetOUT);
        }
        else {
            /* Clear the JDateChooser Text Field since there is
               no date in the selected row anyways.           */
            txtcheckout.setDate(null);
        }
    }
    catch (ParseException ex) {
        // Display error in Console.
        System.err.println("Error Setting Date To Date Chooser!" 
                    + System.lineSeparator() + ex.getMessage());
    }
        
    txtrnumber.setSelectedItem(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,5).toString());
    txtrtype.setSelectedItem(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,6).toString());
    txtbtype.setSelectedItem(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,7).toString());
    txtamount.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex,8).toString());
    
    jButton1.setEnabled(false);

}
```